# NullPointerException while accessing the item values of a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

Listener code:

```
    lvSearch.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) adapter.getChildAt(position);
            TextView tx = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(0);
            TextView tx1 = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(1);
            Log.i("abcValues", tx.getText().toString());
```

I am getting a `NullPointerException` while accessing the item values of a `ListView`. It is working fine for starting item values but not for items that came after scrolling.

Comment: are you using an adapter to fill your list view? If so you should try to handle the clicks from there, Set your ClickListener on the row before you return it from the getView() method. Making it call findViewById() every time an item is clicked will result in somewhat poorer preformance. Also Change "argo0" etc to be more descriptive. Then add Log statements that will show you what values are getting passed to your onItemClick()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getChildAt` returns the visible rows and as you scroll the `LisView` and click the rows you'll call the method `getChildAt` for invalid positions(the maximum number you can use with the `getChildAt` method is the number of visible rows - 1). If you want the parent from the layout of the clicked row, simply use the second parameter `arg1` in your code:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
      LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) arg1;
      TextView tx = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(0);
      TextView tx1 = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(1);
      Log.i("abcValues", tx.getText().toString());
```

Comment: @kamil At what you are referring with `get the child values`? `arg1` is the `View` from the row you have clicked. Then you can access the child `TextView` with `ll.getChildAt` like in the code above or you can find it by id : `ll.findViewById(R.id.textview_id);`. Then you can use it like you want.

Comment: Darnit, beat me to it when I started my answer and had to answer the phone.  +1

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it that way.  Try working your way back up from the View passed in:

```
  LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) arg1.getParent(); 
  TextView tx = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx_id_here);
  TextView tx1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx1_id_here);
```

Comment: You can't call `getParent()` on `arg1` because this will throw an exception as you try to cast a `ListView`(if I remember correctly) to a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: How can i access my list view item on a separate button not on item click listener.

Comment: @kamil You don't do this, it doesn't make sense. What list item are you going to reference when you click a `Button` in your layout(I assumed the `Button` isn't in the list row layout)? You should ask another question.