# NullPointerException while traversing a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

Code:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter ada = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.custom_layout, ssCursor, new String[] {
                        "String" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.txt2 });
        lvSms.setAdapter(ada); 

  btnDel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            private ArrayList<String> msgArr;

            public void onClick(View v) {

                LinearLayout ly = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lv);
                ListView lvMsg = (ListView) ly.getChildAt(3);
                int listCount = lvSms.getCount();
                for (int a = 0 ; a < listCount ; a++)
                {

                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) lvMsg.getChildAt(a);
                    LinearLayout l2 = (LinearLayout) ll.getChildAt(0);
                    LinearLayout l3 = (LinearLayout) l2.getChildAt(0);
                    CheckBox chkBox =(CheckBox) l3.getChildAt(0);
                    boolean valueOfChkBox = chkBox.isChecked();
                    if (valueOfChkBox) {
                        LinearLayout l4 = (LinearLayout) l2.getChildAt(1);
                        TextView txt1 = (TextView) l4.getChildAt(0);
                        msgArr = new ArrayList<String>();
                        msgArr.add(txt1.getText().toString());
                        Log.i("hello", txt1.getText().toString());
                    }

                    } });
```

I am getting a `NullPointerException`, as `getChildAt` returns the visible rows and I have to also check the invisible rows, either they are checked or not. So how could I check it on separate button?

Comment: Could you please add the code where you set the adapter(or if it is a custom adapter add the code for that)?

Comment: @Luksprog i have added the adapter code as per your request. Kindly help...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Not codewise, in general.

Comment: I just need to access the list view items in separate button on click listener. As i have to check the list view items values...

Comment: @kamil That is not the way to do it. As you scroll the `ListView` up and down doesn't your `CheckBoxes` from the list row appear randomly checked/unchecked?

Comment: @Luksprog So how could i do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NullPointerException while accessing the item values of a ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471819/nullpointerexception-while-accessing-the-item-values-of-a-listview)

Comment: @Luksprog You are very much true as I scroll the ListView up and down checkBoxes from the list row appear randomly checked/unchecked. So how can i get rid of it and why it happens so?. Plz help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to obtain the text of the `TextView`s from the rows that are checked in the `ListView`. You can't use `getChildAt()` and just parse all the rows, instead you should use the data that you pass in the adapter, the cursor(and figure out what rows are checked). Because you use a custom row for the layout you'll have to somehow maintain the `checked/unchecked` status of your rows `CheckBoxes`(with a custom adapter). When is time to get the text, at a click of that `Button`, then simply find out what rows are currently checked and extract from the cursor directly the text you want.

A simple way to store the status of the `CheckBoxes` is to have an `ArrayList<Boolean>` that you'll modify depending  on which `CheckBox` you act(probably not that efficient):

```
private class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
            // this will hold the status of the CheckBoxes
        private ArrayList<Boolean> checkItems = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
                String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);
            int count = c.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                checkItems.add(false);
            }

        }

            //this method returns the current status of the CheckBoxes
            //use this to see what CheckBoxes are currently checked
        public ArrayList<Boolean> getItemsThatAreChecked() {
            return checkItems;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
            int position = cursor.getPosition();
            CheckBox ckb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            ckb.setTag(new Integer(position));
            ckb.setChecked(checkItems.get(position));
            ckb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    Integer realPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                    checkItems.set(realPosition, isChecked);
                }

            });
        }

    }
```

Then parse the `ArrayList` you get from `getItemsThatAreChecked()` and extract the data from the cursor. Here you have a small example http://pastebin.com/tsZ6mzt9 (or here git://gist.github.com/2634525.git with the layouts)

Answer (score 0):

`LinearLayout ly = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lv);`

The above line - does it try to take the root layout? If so, you can't use `findViewById`. Rather use:

`getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mylayout)`

`getLayoutInflater()` is Activity's method

Comment: but how can i traverse the list view item??